# Changing Workspace Without Going Into Edit Mode

Tags: workspaces

Looking to see how I can change workspace without it automatically forcing edit mode.

I'm someone that uses this function a whole lot, so this small niggly in your opinion, is a big annoying burden. It breaks the workflow.

I had a small work around for a bitty where when I changed workspace, I had a timer on a script where it would change edit mode to object mode. (but this method fails now)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYjPPjrkzUg

**More description: Only does it when an object is in the scene (regardless if selected or not) and my pie menu is only calling: bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0].workspace = bpy.data.workspaces['Rigging']**

I'll give ya a hug if you can help me out xD

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Changing workspace doesn't automatically switch to edit mode here. If a particular workspace has a 3D view in it, switching to it will mirror the 3D view mode that you'd selected in the previous workspace.

Comment: Uploading video, so you can 100% see the problem

Comment: I'm working on a clunky way. Unhiding an empty, selecting it. then switching workspace, deselecting empty and then hiding. This seems to work... bit over kill tbh!

Comment: Ah ok. I've no experience of that way of working here. Maybe someone else can help now that we can see a video.

Comment: @JohnEason are you sure? The *Modeling* and *UV Editing* workspaces always switch to *Edit* mode. Heading back to the *Layout* workspace always switches to *Object* mode (when you were in *Modeling* or *UV Editing*). But switching between workspaces *Layout* and *Shading* keeps the mode. And the *Texture Paint* workspace always switches to *Texture Paint* mode. But I don't know how this magic works.

Comment: I agree about the Modeling one but TBH I never use it so hadn't tried that one. I suppose it's logical though as you'll want to be in Edit mode if you're modellng. The same applies to the UV one, but at the time it wasn't clear what the OP was referring to.

Answer (score 7):

You can set it in the "Active Tool and Workplace settings" panel:

[image: Active Tool and Workplace settings]

Comment: Thank you so much! This has worked!